# Laravel 5.6 - creation user not working

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

my application used to working well with registration user but now it dont.

here a portion of my model User

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'prenom', 'nom', 'email','photo_path','password',
];
```

here my validation function :

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'prenom' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'nom' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'photo_path' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:10000',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

}
```

here my create function :

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    dd($data);
    $photoInput = request('photo_path');
    $userPhotoPath='users';
    $storagePhotoPath = Storage::disk('images')->put($userPhotoPath, $photoInput);

    return User::create([
        'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
        'nom' => $data['nom'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'photo_path' => $storagePhotoPath,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

- POST request working ( return 302 ) but return back with input value
- Auth Route are declared in web.php
- Validation working well

but the php interpretor didnt get inside create function...

i just see in debugbar that information :

```
The given data was invalid./home/e7250/Laravel/ManageMyWorkLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#306Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException

public function validate()
    {
        if ($this->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($this);
        }

        $data = collect($this->getData())
```

but my validation working because i have error message near my InputTexte.
so i dont understand that error message ...

Do  you have any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to remove the dd(); function before you run something. Other wise it will end the execution of all other operations.

Comment: yes i know but i do it to check if the interpretor came inside create function. the issue is still here with and without dd()

Answer (score 0):

Check if your User Model has a constructor, if so remove it and check if the problem still accours. This fixed it for me.